# Asp .Net session state being lost on iPhone ios

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios

I have a .Net 3.5 web application that uses viewstate to hold some user input between screens. The application works as expected in all desktop browsers, windows phone, and andriod phones.

The problem that I am having is that on an iPhone the session seems to be ending very early or is getting lost altogether. This crashes my application.

I have read some posts like this one about a forms auth issue, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx

I was wondering if this could be a simialr issue? I'm not using forms authentication but am using cookies.

Has anyone ever had the same issue, and if so is there a known fix?

Thank you

Comment: According to the link, this has been fixed when Framework 4.5 is installed. Do you have it installed?

Comment: No we are on an older version and will not be able to update due to company standards (sadly). I will try the suggested fix in the blog. Hopefully it applies to non forms auth session state and cookies as well.

Comment: According to the article, you don't have to change the framework your application is using.  Just install the latest Framework on the server. And given Microsoft security holes, you should have all the latest patches on a machine facing the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an old topic but maybe it helps someone who still doesnt able to solve this.
Make 
      `<sessionState cookieless="true" />` in your web.config under system.web

Comment: This is not a proper solution.